# Телеграмм бот не отправляет txt файл

Tags: python, telebot

```
doc = open('/stat/'+message.text+'.txt', 'rb')
bot.send_document(message.chat.id,doc)
```

Comment: Человек ниже ответил на ваш вопрос. Еще одну поправку вам хочу дать. Вот эту фнукцию open поместите в send document, т.е уберите оттуда doc и поставьте функцию open. Если вы будете отправлять этот же файл несколько раз, то появится ошибка. Так как указатель пойдет в конец

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что:

1. Существует файл с названием `message.txt+'.txt'` в указанной вами директории.
2. При объявлении экземпляра класса telebot вы указали валидный токен.
3. Чат с id `message.chat.id` существует.

Если скрипт возвращает какие либо ошибки, или warning'и, пожалуйста, укажите их в вопросе.